# SoapUI: When I do an update followed by a select in a JDBC Request, I do not see the select result

Tags: soapui

In a JDBC Request I have:

```
select 1 "col"
```

This works fine, on the right in het GUI I see the result.

But when I first do an update, and then the select:

```
update  tempdb..c
set m=2*m
where n=1
select 1 "col"
```

then I see that there is 1 update done, but I do not see the select result anymore. Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried 'commit'?  It might be worth adding an additional JDBC step in between the two you have to include a 'commit' statement.

Comment: @ChrisAdams My SoapUI is autocommit now. I did: begin tran update ... rollback, and that works. So commit is superflous in my case, but an explicit commit also does not help.

Comment: Have you more than one statement in a single JDBC Test Step?